# get index of list by id and by name

Tags: jquery

I have the next li's:

```
<ul id = "myul">
    <li id = "1"> a </li>
    <li id = "2"> b </li>
    <li id = "3"> c </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do two things:

1. I want to get the index of the li by id (for example: 1)
2. I want to get the index of the li by value (for example: b)

for this example, I have to get:

```
1) 0
2) 1
```

I tried the next thing:

```
// get index by id:
alert('index: ' + $("#myul li").index(document.getElementById("2")));

// get index by name
alert('index: ' + );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get index by id:
alert('index: ' + $("#2").index());

// get index by name, works if text does not appear on multiple li
alert('index: ' + $('li:contains(b)').index());
```

Comment: so for my example?
alert('index: ' + $('#myul li:contains(b)').index());

Comment: if "b" is not present on any other `li` then the code I presented would be enough. Adding `#myul` selector will only restrict search to that list.

Answer (score 3):

Just using the index() function of jQuery, as id of element is supposed to be unique so you can use **[id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)** directly.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fg6ja/)**

```
$('#2').index()
```

Answer (score 1):

by value:

```
$("#myul li:contains('b')").index()
```